# Java .jar export paint method puzzle

Tags: java, jar, export, paint

When I exported a Java project to a .jar with Eclipse and tried to run it, to my surprise, everything created by the JPanel paint method was gone! When I ran configurations and debugs, there was no such problem. How do I fix this? P.S. I'm using a Mac. I have also tried running the .jar manually with Terminal.

Comment: What is created in the paint method?  Are you loading images from disc like g.drawImage() or are you using awt methods to draw like g.fillOval()?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am going to take a guess at this one.  I believe that the culprit is bad directory paths to images in the jar file.  You are trying to add images from a bad path and that is why stuff is not showing up in your JPanel.  Otherwise, the program would run normally when executed as a jar because the directory path to your resources is the only thing which is off.  This would also explain why it runs normally from outside of a jar file.